# Codeigniter: Redirecting from construct in Controller

Tags: codeigniter

```
function Home()
{
    parent::Public_Controller();
    $this->load->library('survey_form_processing');
    //Load Helpers
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('Paypal_Lib');
    $this->lang->load('userlib');
    $this->load->model('home_model');
    if($foo == true){
        redirect('home');
    }
}
```

This is my construct of the "Home" controller.  If a value == true, how can I redirect to the index function?  When I try this I get an error...

Is it possible to redirect to the index function?

P.S. I'm a php/CI noob!

Comment: What error do you get ?
What are you trying to achieve ? (maybe you're not on the right path)
I never tried that.

Comment: I'm trying to lock users out of pages if their subscription runs out.  If $expiration_date > $todays_date, redirect back to the index.

Comment: And I just get a browser error--saying that there are too many redirects.

Comment: Are you loading the url helper ? `$this->load->helper('url');` or added "url" in the autoload.php

Comment: Huum ok. I think you have an infinite redirection loop : you're redirecting to a page that redirects again.
You should redirect to another page or add an exception to your redirect rule to prevent redirecting if the function is `index`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I get this error if I use any function in the home controller.  Any idea how to just send the user to the index function if a condition is true?

Comment: You redirection is correct I think, just change your redirection as explained in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided, I'd say that you're stuck in an infinite redirection loop :

- The user goes to the Home page
- In the constructor, it checks the subscription and if it fails, it redirects to Home
- ==> loop !

You may have some solutions :

- Detect that the method called is `index` and in that case don't redirect (you can use the function `router->fetch_method()`
- Perform the redirection to another Controller
- Don't perform the redirection in the constructor but in each Function. You just have to put the subscription control in a function and call it at the beginning of each function.

The easiest would probably to change your condition.
From

```
if($foo == true)
```

To

```
if($foo == true && router->fetch_method() != 'index')
```

So that if CodeIgniter is trying to reach the Index it won't be redirected again.

*(I don't have a php server here so I can't check the exact value). But the idea is here.*

Comment: Very close.  Now that it's almost working, I don't know if this is the best method for me, but you got the question answered!

Comment: If I was you, I'd do a default Controller, accessible to everyone, the "Home" and all the content that need a subscription should be under another Controller. You add your redirection only on the second one, and you redirect to the first one.